# Bootstrap 3 слайдер. Как менять позицию и размер caption блока для конкретного слайда?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <h1>Слайд 1</h1>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
        <h3>Подзаголовок 1</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-red">Кнопка 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Слайд 2</h1>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
        <h3>Подзаголовок 2</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-red">Кнопка 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    Нечто
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: С помощью css..

Answer (score 1):

1. Введите дополнительные классы для заголовков и меняйте размер, цвет и отступы с помощью стилей.
2. У вас семантически не верная верстка заголовок `h1` должен быть на странице один. Или как минимум должен быть обернут в `article` или `section`.

```css
.caption_1{
  margin:10px 0 20px;
  color:red;
  font-size:4rem;
}
.caption_2{
  margin:10px 30px 20px;
  color:green;
  font-size:6rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <h1 class="caption_1">Слайд 1</h1>
      <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption_1">
        <h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
        <h3>Подзаголовок 1</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-red">Кнопка 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1 class="caption_2">Слайд 2</h1>
      <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption_2">
        <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
        <h3>Подзаголовок 2</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-red">Кнопка 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    Нечто
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```